# bigquery php client not working with Apache web page (Ubuntu 18.10 server)

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, google-bigquery

I have a working Apache 2.4 website that works with Php 7 pages, on an Ubuntu 18.10 server.

My example is based on:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-php

When I run the page as me from the command line

```
php filex.php
```

bigquery works and I can see the data.
When I try and view it from the apache web server the 1st part of the page renders then there is an error and the bigquery part is missing.

Error in  /var/log/apache2

PHP fatal error Uncaught Google Cloud Exception

Answer (score 2):

I guessed it was a permissions issue with Apache vs my userid.
I thought Apache might be having difficulty accessing the Bigquery php client files, due to directory permissions.

However, the problem was I had not set the environment variable correctly.

I had looked here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables
and set System-wide environment variables
/etc/environment

```
 GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/bigquery/project1/accountdetails-xxxxxxxxxxxx.json"
```

It was visible when logged in as userx

```
 echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

Then I came across 
https://medium.com/@william.b/setting-dynamic-environmental-variables-in-apache-from-the-os-1d5c1e2e9e6c

which gave me the solution

```
 nano /etc/apache2/envvars
```

I added the line to the bottom of the (mainly empty)  script

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/bigquery/project1/accountdetails-xxxxxxxxxxxx.json"
```

I restarted the server.
Now the web page works as expected.

===================

**Nginx**

nginx also needs to be configured to work  (Ubuntu 18.10, nginx 1.14.)

from
https://medium.com/@tomahock/passing-system-environment-variables-to-php-fpm-when-using-nginx-a70045370fad

/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d$

edited www.conf

```
uncomment 
;clear_env = no
```

added line

```
env[GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS] = /bigquery/project1/accountdetails-xxxxxxxxxxxx.json
```

restarted nginx and it worked.

Comment: this is rather complicated, because one can load that `.json` file in PHP... and alike this, one can even have more than 1 single project per server - which is not possible when setting global environmental variables - and this also limits the portability of the script (eg. one a shared hosting one would have no chance to do that).